# facebook rss - how to increase thumbs image size?

Tags: facebook, rss

I'm accessing a facebook-rss through

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=...
```

**Update:** Actual URL:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=170589069647190
```

However, the thumbs for the images are way to small. Is it possible to change the size of the tumbs with rss-arg or FB-page setting?

(or should I get the FB-posts in another way)

regards,

Comment: there's a 2:nd part related to this matter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409210/howto-extract-events-from-facebook-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for this, it's far more robust, versatile, and better maintained.

1. Start at the `/PAGE_ID/feed` endpoint, so in your example `/170589069647190/feed`. (Play around in the [explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test it) Great, now you have the same list of posts as that RSS feed. Note that each post with a photo has an `object_id` field.
2. For each `object_id`, go to the endpoint `/OBJECT_ID?fields=images,height,width,source`. If you're doing multiple of them, it's best to [batch them together](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) for efficiency

Those 2 simple steps will give you this data for each photo status update. The outside `height`,`width` and `source` are the orginial upload dimensions and source. But the `images` array provides you with a bunch of resized images. Choose the one most appropriate for your needs.

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 2048, 
      "width": 1365, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s2048x2048/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 960, 
      "width": 640, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 720, 
      "width": 480, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s720x720/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 600, 
      "width": 400, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s600x600/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 480, 
      "width": 320, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s480x480/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 320, 
      "width": 213, 
      "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s320x320/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 270, 
      "width": 180, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_a.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 130, 
      "width": 86, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_s.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 130, 
      "width": 86, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s75x225/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_s.jpg"
    }
  ], 
  "height": 720, 
  "width": 480, 
  "source": "https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc7/s720x720/599910_508618522510908_1608434210_n.jpg", 
  "id": "508618522510908", 
  "created_time": "2013-03-04T11:05:09+0000"
}
```

NOTE: In order to do this on the fly, you'll need to a [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/).

Comment: Big thanks for this excellent answer. It's time to take the red pill and learn the graph api.

Comment: @Tommy\ Crush is it possible to make a batch request in the whole feed with getting image dimensions in one call? i have tried a few things but i didnt get that together.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer**: 
This is not a good method as Facebook may change the image path anytime.

That been said, for every image with this file name format:
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_s.jpg`

You can change the letter "s" just before the ".jpg" to "n" and get a bigger version like so:
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_n.jpg`

Changing it to "q" will give you an image with a width of no more then 180 pixels
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_q.jpg`