# Facebook Rss Feed retrieve original image of thumbnail.

Tags: facebook, rss, feed, atom-feed

I using this format of Facebook rss feed (format=atom10). I have problem with images all images are thumbnails they are very small now I want to get original size.
example feed

```
 https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=193742123995472&format=atom10
```

image src= link

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCdnW-j48FEyfew&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn3.vox-cdn.com%2Fuploads%2Fchorus_image%2Fimage%2F36268722%2Fhateful-iimage-7-30.0_cinema_1200.0.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the image URL, remove everything up to `...url=`, replace the escaped characters

- `%3A` -> `:`
- `%2F` -> `/`

and you get what you want: `http://cdn3.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/36268722/hateful-iimage-7-30.0_cinema_1200.0.jpg`

---

You might also consider using the facebook Graph API. See this: [facebook rss - how to increase thumbs image size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934385/facebook-rss-how-to-increase-thumbs-image-size?rq=1)